# Order numbers within a tabular

Tags: tables, macros, xparse

Given a set of numbers from 1 to 57. Arrange a subset of 8 distinct numbers within a table, where the number should be the number of the column.

I'd like to produce a 57 x 57 table, where the number of the 8 numbers' subset is set within the column of its number.

The subset of the 8 numbers are already ordered in ascending order.

Here the 57 subset of 8 numbers to be ordered into a table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\{1,\, 2,\, 22,\, 29,\, 37,\, 41,\, 51,\, 55\}\\
\{1,\, 3,\, 5,\, 26,\, 38,\, 42,\, 46,\, 50\}\\
\{1,\, 4,\, 11,\, 13,\, 16,\, 23,\, 24,\, 45\}\\
\{1,\, 6,\, 8,\, 27,\, 32,\, 35,\, 40,\, 57\}\\
\{1,\, 7,\, 20,\, 21,\, 31,\, 36,\, 44,\, 49\}\\
\{1,\, 9,\, 14,\, 17,\, 39,\, 43,\, 53,\, 54\}\\
\{1,\, 10,\, 25,\, 30,\, 33,\, 48,\, 52,\, 56\}\\
\{1,\, 12,\, 15,\, 18,\, 19,\, 28,\, 34,\, 47\}\\
\{2,\, 3,\, 11,\, 12,\, 20,\, 35,\, 43,\, 56\}\\
\{2,\, 4,\, 7,\, 18,\, 26,\, 27,\, 30,\, 54\}\\
\{2,\, 5,\, 19,\, 39,\, 40,\, 44,\, 45,\, 52\}\\
\{2,\, 6,\, 13,\, 17,\, 21,\, 28,\, 42,\, 48\}\\
\{2,\, 8,\, 10,\, 14,\, 16,\, 47,\, 49,\, 50\}\\
\{2,\, 9,\, 15,\, 24,\, 25,\, 36,\, 38,\, 57\}\\
\{2,\, 23,\, 31,\, 32,\, 33,\, 34,\, 46,\, 53\}\\
\{3,\, 4,\, 15,\, 32,\, 39,\, 41,\, 48,\, 49\}\\
\{3,\, 6,\, 9,\, 23,\, 30,\, 44,\, 47,\, 51\}\\
\{3,\, 7,\, 8,\, 24,\, 28,\, 37,\, 52,\, 53\}\\
\{3,\, 10,\, 21,\, 29,\, 34,\, 45,\, 54,\, 57\}\\
\{3,\, 13,\, 14,\, 19,\, 22,\, 27,\, 33,\, 36\}\\
\{3,\, 16,\, 17,\, 18,\, 25,\, 31,\, 40,\, 55\}\\
\{4,\, 5,\, 21,\, 22,\, 25,\, 35,\, 47,\, 53\}\\
\{4,\, 6,\, 14,\, 20,\, 34,\, 38,\, 52,\, 55\}\\
\{4,\, 8,\, 9,\, 19,\, 29,\, 31,\, 42,\, 56\}\\
\{4,\, 10,\, 28,\, 36,\, 40,\, 43,\, 46,\, 51\}\\
\{4,\, 12,\, 17,\, 33,\, 37,\, 44,\, 50,\, 57\}\\
\{5,\, 6,\, 7,\, 15,\, 16,\, 29,\, 33,\, 43\}\\
\{5,\, 8,\, 12,\, 23,\, 36,\, 48,\, 54,\, 55\}\\
\{5,\, 9,\, 10,\, 13,\, 18,\, 20,\, 32,\, 37\}\\
\{5,\, 11,\, 14,\, 28,\, 30,\, 31,\, 41,\, 57\}\\
\{5,\, 17,\, 24,\, 27,\, 34,\, 49,\, 51,\, 56\}\\
\{6,\, 10,\, 12,\, 22,\, 24,\, 26,\, 31,\, 39\}\\
\{6,\, 11,\, 19,\, 25,\, 37,\, 46,\, 49,\, 54\}\\
\{6,\, 18,\, 36,\, 41,\, 45,\, 50,\, 53,\, 56\}\\
\{7,\, 9,\, 11,\, 22,\, 34,\, 40,\, 48,\, 50\}\\
\{7,\, 10,\, 17,\, 19,\, 23,\, 35,\, 38,\, 41\}\\
\{7,\, 12,\, 14,\, 25,\, 32,\, 42,\, 45,\, 51\}\\
\{7,\, 13,\, 39,\, 46,\, 47,\, 55,\, 56,\, 57\}\\
\{8,\, 11,\, 18,\, 21,\, 33,\, 38,\, 39,\, 51\}\\
\{8,\, 13,\, 25,\, 26,\, 34,\, 41,\, 43,\, 44\}\\
\{8,\, 15,\, 17,\, 20,\, 22,\, 30,\, 45,\, 46\}\\
\{9,\, 12,\, 16,\, 21,\, 27,\, 41,\, 46,\, 52\}\\
\{9,\, 26,\, 28,\, 33,\, 35,\, 45,\, 49,\, 55\}\\
\{10,\, 11,\, 15,\, 27,\, 42,\, 44,\, 53,\, 55\}\\
\{11,\, 17,\, 26,\, 29,\, 32,\, 36,\, 47,\, 52\}\\
\{12,\, 13,\, 29,\, 30,\, 38,\, 40,\, 49,\, 53\}\\
\{13,\, 15,\, 31,\, 35,\, 50,\, 51,\, 52,\, 54\}\\
\{14,\, 15,\, 21,\, 23,\, 26,\, 37,\, 40,\, 56\}\\
\{14,\, 18,\, 24,\, 29,\, 35,\, 44,\, 46,\, 48\}\\
\{16,\, 19,\, 20,\, 26,\, 48,\, 51,\, 53,\, 57\}\\
\{16,\, 22,\, 28,\, 32,\, 38,\, 44,\, 54,\, 56\}\\
\{16,\, 30,\, 34,\, 35,\, 36,\, 37,\, 39,\, 42\}\\
\{18,\, 22,\, 23,\, 42,\, 43,\, 49,\, 52,\, 57\}\\
\{19,\, 21,\, 24,\, 30,\, 32,\, 43,\, 50,\, 55\}\\
\{20,\, 23,\, 25,\, 27,\, 28,\, 29,\, 39,\, 50\}\\
\{20,\, 24,\, 33,\, 40,\, 41,\, 42,\, 47,\, 54\}\\
\{27,\, 31,\, 37,\, 38,\, 43,\, 45,\, 47,\, 48\}
\end{document}
```

I hope I was precise enough to make you understand, what I like to have.

Any hints appreciated.

Regards,

Jürgen

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, do you mean like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\addtolength\textwidth{2cm}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-2cm}

\def\zz#1 {%
\ifx\\#1\par\else
\noindent\makebox[0pt]{\kern\dimexpr(2em)*#1\relax\llap{#1}}%
\expandafter\zz
\fi}
\begin{document}

\tiny

\noindent X\dotfill X

\zz 1 2 22 29 37 41 51 55 \\
\zz 1 3 5 26 38 42 46 50 \\
\zz 1 4 11 13 16 23 24 45 \\
\zz 1 6 8 27 32 35 40 57 \\
\zz 1 7 20 21 31 36 44 49 \\
\zz 1 9 14 17 39 43 53 54 \\
\zz 1 10 25 30 33 48 52 56 \\
\zz 1 12 15 18 19 28 34 47 \\
\zz 2 3 11 12 20 35 43 56 \\
\zz 2 4 7 18 26 27 30 54 \\
\zz 2 5 19 39 40 44 45 52 \\
\zz 2 6 13 17 21 28 42 48 \\
\zz 2 8 10 14 16 47 49 50 \\
\zz 2 9 15 24 25 36 38 57 \\
\zz 2 23 31 32 33 34 46 53 \\
\zz 3 4 15 32 39 41 48 49 \\
\zz 3 6 9 23 30 44 47 51 \\
\zz 3 7 8 24 28 37 52 53 \\
\zz 3 10 21 29 34 45 54 57 \\
\zz 3 13 14 19 22 27 33 36 \\
\zz 3 16 17 18 25 31 40 55 \\
\zz 4 5 21 22 25 35 47 53 \\
\zz 4 6 14 20 34 38 52 55 \\
\zz 4 8 9 19 29 31 42 56 \\
\zz 4 10 28 36 40 43 46 51 \\
\zz 4 12 17 33 37 44 50 57 \\
\zz 5 6 7 15 16 29 33 43 \\
\zz 5 8 12 23 36 48 54 55 \\
\zz 5 9 10 13 18 20 32 37 \\
\zz 5 11 14 28 30 31 41 57 \\
\zz 5 17 24 27 34 49 51 56 \\
\zz 6 10 12 22 24 26 31 39 \\
\zz 6 11 19 25 37 46 49 54 \\
\zz 6 18 36 41 45 50 53 56 \\
\zz 7 9 11 22 34 40 48 50 \\
\zz 7 10 17 19 23 35 38 41 \\
\zz 7 12 14 25 32 42 45 51 \\
\zz 7 13 39 46 47 55 56 57 \\
\zz 8 11 18 21 33 38 39 51 \\
\zz 8 13 25 26 34 41 43 44 \\
\zz 8 15 17 20 22 30 45 46 \\
\zz 9 12 16 21 27 41 46 52 \\
\zz 9 26 28 33 35 45 49 55 \\
\zz 10 11 15 27 42 44 53 55 \\
\zz 11 17 26 29 32 36 47 52 \\
\zz 12 13 29 30 38 40 49 53 \\
\zz 13 15 31 35 50 51 52 54 \\
\zz 14 15 21 23 26 37 40 56 \\
\zz 14 18 24 29 35 44 46 48 \\
\zz 16 19 20 26 48 51 53 57 \\
\zz 16 22 28 32 38 44 54 56 \\
\zz 16 30 34 35 36 37 39 42 \\
\zz 18 22 23 42 43 49 52 57 \\
\zz 19 21 24 30 32 43 50 55 \\
\zz 20 23 25 27 28 29 39 50 \\
\zz 20 24 33 40 41 42 47 54 \\
\zz 27 31 37 38 43 45 47 48 \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: We should notify Paulo, some ducks can be seen in the clouds of numbers. :-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek oh no, not you as well, I thought you were an island of sanity in the general sea of duck silliness:-)

Comment: David,

exactly that was it, what I needed!

I can now do some finetuning myself.

:-)

Answer (score 2):

A table version, generated by a small Python script (faster and easier to maintain than programming in TeX):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

data = [
    [1, 2, 22, 29, 37, 41, 51, 55],
    [1, 3, 5, 26, 38, 42, 46, 50],
    [1, 4, 11, 13, 16, 23, 24, 45],
    [1, 6, 8, 27, 32, 35, 40, 57],
    [1, 7, 20, 21, 31, 36, 44, 49],
    [1, 9, 14, 17, 39, 43, 53, 54],
    [1, 10, 25, 30, 33, 48, 52, 56],
    [1, 12, 15, 18, 19, 28, 34, 47],
    [2, 3, 11, 12, 20, 35, 43, 56],
    [2, 4, 7, 18, 26, 27, 30, 54],
    [2, 5, 19, 39, 40, 44, 45, 52],
    [2, 6, 13, 17, 21, 28, 42, 48],
    [2, 8, 10, 14, 16, 47, 49, 50],
    [2, 9, 15, 24, 25, 36, 38, 57],
    [2, 23, 31, 32, 33, 34, 46, 53],
    [3, 4, 15, 32, 39, 41, 48, 49],
    [3, 6, 9, 23, 30, 44, 47, 51],
    [3, 7, 8, 24, 28, 37, 52, 53],
    [3, 10, 21, 29, 34, 45, 54, 57],
    [3, 13, 14, 19, 22, 27, 33, 36],
    [3, 16, 17, 18, 25, 31, 40, 55],
    [4, 5, 21, 22, 25, 35, 47, 53],
    [4, 6, 14, 20, 34, 38, 52, 55],
    [4, 8, 9, 19, 29, 31, 42, 56],
    [4, 10, 28, 36, 40, 43, 46, 51],
    [4, 12, 17, 33, 37, 44, 50, 57],
    [5, 6, 7, 15, 16, 29, 33, 43],
    [5, 8, 12, 23, 36, 48, 54, 55],
    [5, 9, 10, 13, 18, 20, 32, 37],
    [5, 11, 14, 28, 30, 31, 41, 57],
    [5, 17, 24, 27, 34, 49, 51, 56],
    [6, 10, 12, 22, 24, 26, 31, 39],
    [6, 11, 19, 25, 37, 46, 49, 54],
    [6, 18, 36, 41, 45, 50, 53, 56],
    [7, 9, 11, 22, 34, 40, 48, 50],
    [7, 10, 17, 19, 23, 35, 38, 41],
    [7, 12, 14, 25, 32, 42, 45, 51],
    [7, 13, 39, 46, 47, 55, 56, 57],
    [8, 11, 18, 21, 33, 38, 39, 51],
    [8, 13, 25, 26, 34, 41, 43, 44],
    [8, 15, 17, 20, 22, 30, 45, 46],
    [9, 12, 16, 21, 27, 41, 46, 52],
    [9, 26, 28, 33, 35, 45, 49, 55],
    [10, 11, 15, 27, 42, 44, 53, 55],
    [11, 17, 26, 29, 32, 36, 47, 52],
    [12, 13, 29, 30, 38, 40, 49, 53],
    [13, 15, 31, 35, 50, 51, 52, 54],
    [14, 15, 21, 23, 26, 37, 40, 56],
    [14, 18, 24, 29, 35, 44, 46, 48],
    [16, 19, 20, 26, 48, 51, 53, 57],
    [16, 22, 28, 32, 38, 44, 54, 56],
    [16, 30, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 42],
    [18, 22, 23, 42, 43, 49, 52, 57],
    [19, 21, 24, 30, 32, 43, 50, 55],
    [20, 23, 25, 27, 28, 29, 39, 50],
    [20, 24, 33, 40, 41, 42, 47, 54],
    [27, 31, 37, 38, 43, 45, 47, 48],
]

print(r'\documentclass{standalone}')
print(r'\begin{document}')
print(r'\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.25em}')
print(r'\begin{tabular}{*{57}{r}}')

for row in data:
    nums = set(row)
    line = ''
    for i in range(1, 58):
        if i in nums:
            line += str(i)

        if i < 57:
            line += '&'
        else:
            line += r'\\'

    print(line)

print(r'\end{tabular}')
print(r'\end{document}')
```

It generates a standalone LaTeX file on the console that can be redirected to a LaTeX file:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.25em}
\begin{tabular}{*{57}{r}}
1&2&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&22&&&&&&&29&&&&&&&&37&&&&41&&&&&&&&&&51&&&&55&&\\
1&&3&&5&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&26&&&&&&&&&&&&38&&&&42&&&&46&&&&50&&&&&&&\\
1&&&4&&&&&&&11&&13&&&16&&&&&&&23&24&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&45&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
1&&&&&6&&8&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&27&&&&&32&&&35&&&&&40&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&57\\
1&&&&&&7&&&&&&&&&&&&&20&21&&&&&&&&&&31&&&&&36&&&&&&&&44&&&&&49&&&&&&&&\\
1&&&&&&&&9&&&&&14&&&17&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&39&&&&43&&&&&&&&&&53&54&&&\\
1&&&&&&&&&10&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&25&&&&&30&&&33&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&48&&&&52&&&&56&\\
1&&&&&&&&&&&12&&&15&&&18&19&&&&&&&&&28&&&&&&34&&&&&&&&&&&&&47&&&&&&&&&&\\
&2&3&&&&&&&&11&12&&&&&&&&20&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&35&&&&&&&&43&&&&&&&&&&&&&56&\\
&2&&4&&&7&&&&&&&&&&&18&&&&&&&&26&27&&&30&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&54&&&\\
&2&&&5&&&&&&&&&&&&&&19&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&39&40&&&&44&45&&&&&&&52&&&&&\\
&2&&&&6&&&&&&&13&&&&17&&&&21&&&&&&&28&&&&&&&&&&&&&&42&&&&&&48&&&&&&&&&\\
&2&&&&&&8&&10&&&&14&&16&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&47&&49&50&&&&&&&\\
&2&&&&&&&9&&&&&&15&&&&&&&&&24&25&&&&&&&&&&&36&&38&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&57\\
&2&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&23&&&&&&&&31&32&33&34&&&&&&&&&&&&46&&&&&&&53&&&&\\
&&3&4&&&&&&&&&&&15&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&32&&&&&&&39&&41&&&&&&&48&49&&&&&&&&\\
&&3&&&6&&&9&&&&&&&&&&&&&&23&&&&&&&30&&&&&&&&&&&&&&44&&&47&&&&51&&&&&&\\
&&3&&&&7&8&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&24&&&&28&&&&&&&&&37&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&52&53&&&&\\
&&3&&&&&&&10&&&&&&&&&&&21&&&&&&&&29&&&&&34&&&&&&&&&&&45&&&&&&&&&54&&&57\\
&&3&&&&&&&&&&13&14&&&&&19&&&22&&&&&27&&&&&&33&&&36&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&3&&&&&&&&&&&&&16&17&18&&&&&&&25&&&&&&31&&&&&&&&&40&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&55&&\\
&&&4&5&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&21&22&&&25&&&&&&&&&&35&&&&&&&&&&&&47&&&&&&53&&&&\\
&&&4&&6&&&&&&&&14&&&&&&20&&&&&&&&&&&&&&34&&&&38&&&&&&&&&&&&&&52&&&55&&\\
&&&4&&&&8&9&&&&&&&&&&19&&&&&&&&&&29&&31&&&&&&&&&&&42&&&&&&&&&&&&&&56&\\
&&&4&&&&&&10&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&28&&&&&&&&36&&&&40&&&43&&&46&&&&&51&&&&&&\\
&&&4&&&&&&&&12&&&&&17&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&33&&&&37&&&&&&&44&&&&&&50&&&&&&&57\\
&&&&5&6&7&&&&&&&&15&16&&&&&&&&&&&&&29&&&&33&&&&&&&&&&43&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&5&&&8&&&&12&&&&&&&&&&&23&&&&&&&&&&&&&36&&&&&&&&&&&&48&&&&&&54&55&&\\
&&&&5&&&&9&10&&&13&&&&&18&&20&&&&&&&&&&&&32&&&&&37&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&5&&&&&&11&&&14&&&&&&&&&&&&&&28&&30&31&&&&&&&&&&41&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&57\\
&&&&5&&&&&&&&&&&&17&&&&&&&24&&&27&&&&&&&34&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&49&&51&&&&&56&\\
&&&&&6&&&&10&&12&&&&&&&&&&22&&24&&26&&&&&31&&&&&&&&39&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&6&&&&&11&&&&&&&&19&&&&&&25&&&&&&&&&&&&37&&&&&&&&&46&&&49&&&&&54&&&\\
&&&&&6&&&&&&&&&&&&18&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&36&&&&&41&&&&45&&&&&50&&&53&&&56&\\
&&&&&&7&&9&&11&&&&&&&&&&&22&&&&&&&&&&&&34&&&&&&40&&&&&&&&48&&50&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&7&&&10&&&&&&&17&&19&&&&23&&&&&&&&&&&&35&&&38&&&41&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&7&&&&&12&&14&&&&&&&&&&&25&&&&&&&32&&&&&&&&&&42&&&45&&&&&&51&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&7&&&&&&13&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&39&&&&&&&46&47&&&&&&&&55&56&57\\
&&&&&&&8&&&11&&&&&&&18&&&21&&&&&&&&&&&&33&&&&&38&39&&&&&&&&&&&&51&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&8&&&&&13&&&&&&&&&&&&25&26&&&&&&&&34&&&&&&&41&&43&44&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&8&&&&&&&15&&17&&&20&&22&&&&&&&&30&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&45&46&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&9&&&12&&&&16&&&&&21&&&&&&27&&&&&&&&&&&&&&41&&&&&46&&&&&&52&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&9&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&26&&28&&&&&33&&35&&&&&&&&&&45&&&&49&&&&&&55&&\\
&&&&&&&&&10&11&&&&15&&&&&&&&&&&&27&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&42&&44&&&&&&&&&53&&55&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&11&&&&&&17&&&&&&&&&26&&&29&&&32&&&&36&&&&&&&&&&&47&&&&&52&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&12&13&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&29&30&&&&&&&&38&&40&&&&&&&&&49&&&&53&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&13&&15&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&31&&&&35&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&50&51&52&&54&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&14&15&&&&&&21&&23&&&26&&&&&&&&&&&37&&&40&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&56&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&14&&&&18&&&&&&24&&&&&29&&&&&&35&&&&&&&&&44&&46&&48&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&16&&&19&20&&&&&&26&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&48&&&51&&53&&&&57\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&16&&&&&&22&&&&&&28&&&&32&&&&&&38&&&&&&44&&&&&&&&&&54&&56&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&16&&&&&&&&&&&&&&30&&&&34&35&36&37&&39&&&42&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&18&&&&22&23&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&42&43&&&&&&49&&&52&&&&&57\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&19&&21&&&24&&&&&&30&&32&&&&&&&&&&&43&&&&&&&50&&&&&55&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&20&&&23&&25&&27&28&29&&&&&&&&&&39&&&&&&&&&&&50&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&20&&&&24&&&&&&&&&33&&&&&&&40&41&42&&&&&47&&&&&&&54&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&27&&&&31&&&&&&37&38&&&&&43&&45&&47&48&&&&&&&&&\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Is this some kind of art project?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the table approach. No art project at all. It is about to show visually best possible the mathematics behind the card game "Dobble" (for children).

Answer (score 2):

No Python, no `\zz`, but `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % wider text
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\printfancytable}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_clear:N \l_juergen_table_tl
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_juergen_data_clist
   {
    \juergen_makefancyrow:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
   }
  \par\noindent\tiny
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{#1}{r@{}}}
  \tl_use:N \l_juergen_table_tl
  \end{tabular*}\par
  \group_end:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printtable}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_clear:N \l_juergen_table_tl
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_juergen_data_clist
   {
    \juergen_makerow:n { ##1 }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{@{$\{$}*{\int_eval:n{#1-1}}{r@{, }}r@{$\}$}}
  \hline
  \tl_use:N \l_juergen_table_tl
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \group_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setdata}{m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \l_juergen_data_clist { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_juergen_table_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \juergen_makefancyrow:nn
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 - 1 }
   {
    \clist_if_in:nnT { #2 } { ##1 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_juergen_table_tl { ##1 }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_juergen_table_tl { & }
   }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #2 } { #1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_juergen_table_tl { #1 }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_juergen_table_tl { \\ }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \juergen_makerow:n
 {
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_juergen_table_tl
   {
    \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { & }
    \exp_not:N \\
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setdata{
  {1, 2, 22, 29, 37, 41, 51, 55},
  {1, 3, 5, 26, 38, 42, 46, 50},
  {1, 4, 11, 13, 16, 23, 24, 45},
  {1, 6, 8, 27, 32, 35, 40, 57},
  {1, 7, 20, 21, 31, 36, 44, 49},
  {1, 9, 14, 17, 39, 43, 53, 54},
  {1, 10, 25, 30, 33, 48, 52, 56},
  {1, 12, 15, 18, 19, 28, 34, 47},
  {2, 3, 11, 12, 20, 35, 43, 56},
  {2, 4, 7, 18, 26, 27, 30, 54},
  {2, 5, 19, 39, 40, 44, 45, 52},
  {2, 6, 13, 17, 21, 28, 42, 48},
  {2, 8, 10, 14, 16, 47, 49, 50},
  {2, 9, 15, 24, 25, 36, 38, 57},
  {2, 23, 31, 32, 33, 34, 46, 53},
  {3, 4, 15, 32, 39, 41, 48, 49},
  {3, 6, 9, 23, 30, 44, 47, 51},
  {3, 7, 8, 24, 28, 37, 52, 53},
  {3, 10, 21, 29, 34, 45, 54, 57},
  {3, 13, 14, 19, 22, 27, 33, 36},
  {3, 16, 17, 18, 25, 31, 40, 55},
  {4, 5, 21, 22, 25, 35, 47, 53},
  {4, 6, 14, 20, 34, 38, 52, 55},
  {4, 8, 9, 19, 29, 31, 42, 56},
  {4, 10, 28, 36, 40, 43, 46, 51},
  {4, 12, 17, 33, 37, 44, 50, 57},
  {5, 6, 7, 15, 16, 29, 33, 43},
  {5, 8, 12, 23, 36, 48, 54, 55},
  {5, 9, 10, 13, 18, 20, 32, 37},
  {5, 11, 14, 28, 30, 31, 41, 57},
  {5, 17, 24, 27, 34, 49, 51, 56},
  {6, 10, 12, 22, 24, 26, 31, 39},
  {6, 11, 19, 25, 37, 46, 49, 54},
  {6, 18, 36, 41, 45, 50, 53, 56},
  {7, 9, 11, 22, 34, 40, 48, 50},
  {7, 10, 17, 19, 23, 35, 38, 41},
  {7, 12, 14, 25, 32, 42, 45, 51},
  {7, 13, 39, 46, 47, 55, 56, 57},
  {8, 11, 18, 21, 33, 38, 39, 51},
  {8, 13, 25, 26, 34, 41, 43, 44},
  {8, 15, 17, 20, 22, 30, 45, 46},
  {9, 12, 16, 21, 27, 41, 46, 52},
  {9, 26, 28, 33, 35, 45, 49, 55},
  {10, 11, 15, 27, 42, 44, 53, 55},
  {11, 17, 26, 29, 32, 36, 47, 52},
  {12, 13, 29, 30, 38, 40, 49, 53},
  {13, 15, 31, 35, 50, 51, 52, 54},
  {14, 15, 21, 23, 26, 37, 40, 56},
  {14, 18, 24, 29, 35, 44, 46, 48},
  {16, 19, 20, 26, 48, 51, 53, 57},
  {16, 22, 28, 32, 38, 44, 54, 56},
  {16, 30, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 42},
  {18, 22, 23, 42, 43, 49, 52, 57},
  {19, 21, 24, 30, 32, 43, 50, 55},
  {20, 23, 25, 27, 28, 29, 39, 50},
  {20, 24, 33, 40, 41, 42, 47, 54},
  {27, 31, 37, 38, 43, 45, 47, 48}
 }

\printfancytable{57}

{\footnotesize\printtable{8}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WOW - what an approach with expl3. Many thanks for the time you spent for my problem.